# Sentry javascript integration with Raven.JS

Tags: javascript, sentry

My JS code to get it working is

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.26.4/raven.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function (argument) {
        Raven.config('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxx').install();
    });
</script>
```

But it does not sending console error to sentry, though

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.26.4/raven.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function (argument) {
        Raven.config('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxx').install();
        Raven.captureException("catch error");
    });
</script>
```

will send `catch error` to sentry
also tried to catch error manually & send it to sentry that is also not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function (argument) {
        Raven.config('https://d28cbc1dcf354e91aefb0bc3480dd7d4@sentry.io/1214721').install();
    });
    window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
        Raven.captureException(error);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

What does I am missing?

Comment: removing ```$(window).load(function (argument) {``` has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

removing `$(window).load(function (argument) {});` has worked for me. Just place `Raven.config('https://d28cbc1dcf354e91aefb0bc3480dd7d4@sentry.io/1214721').install();` directly after `jquery.js` file